# With Organize Imports, what does Eclipse use to decide the import order for non-specifed packages?

Tags: java, eclipse, import

I'm using the standard import ordering in eclipse.

```
java
javax
org
com
```

However, when I organize the imports in a source file, the packages that don't match these prefixes are inserted between org and com.

Eg,

```
import java.util.List;

import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import org.junit.Before;

import an.other.package.Here;

import com.google.common.collect.FluentIterable;
```

This seems odd to me. You can specify where everything else goes with a wildcard, so to make this behaviour explicit I altered the import ordering to be:

```
java
javax
org
* - all unmatched type imports
com
```

However is this really what's going on when there is no wildcard specified in the default settings?

Comment: The order does not matter at all. If there is a conflict then there just is and if not then it's just fine.

Comment: `org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.dom.rewrite.ImportRewriteAnalyzer` deals with the order but it is complex code.

Comment: @Eypros the ordering matters from the point-of-view of writing clear, maintainable code. That's why Eclipse allows you to organize them

Comment: This matters as we have users with IDEA and users with Eclipse. To avoid merge conflicts and unnecessary noise we want to keep the import order the same when organizing them in different IDEs. On the IDEA side the settings are clear in terms of where the unmatched type imports go. With eclipse the settings out of the box are not clear.

Answer (score -2):

Use Cntrl + O to organise your imports in ECLIPSE

Comment: It is obvious. OP asks what kind of logic is used by Eclipse when it sorts import statements of not-standard packages.